# PHP: require versus include: practical considerations?

Tags: php, include, require

I've read that one of the differences between include and require is that
while include only includes the included file if the include statement is
encountered, require includes the file into the file hosting the require
statement even when the require code is not reached by the execution flow.

How can this have any implications. After all, if I have a file which says:

```
<?php
  echo __LINE__;
?>
```

the output will always be 3, instead of printing the line inside at the
position inside the file which includes such include file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are running a mission critical application and will lose $1 per second. And some libraries are only used in certain case and are not affecting your business flow. You should probably use **include_once** for these optional libraries. Because if the file is not there **require** will stop your application from running with a fatal error.

Answer (score 7):

This is simply not true, as far as I know. If the `require` line is not reached in the code, the file will certainly not be included.

[The PHP Manual on `require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) states:

> `require` is identical to `include` *except* upon failure it will also
>   produce a fatal **E_COMPILE_ERROR** level error.

<sup>(emphasis on "except" added by me)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that's not how require works. The only practical difference is that require will cause your script to terminate if the file cannot be included, and include will just throw a warning and keep executing.

A very important idiom depends on your stated behavior not being true: conditional required files.

```
if(is_secure_page()) {
  require "security.php";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `require` and `include` include their files at the point where they are reached in the execution flow.

A simple test case for this is:

```
if (false) {
  require_once("Nonexistent.php");
}
echo "I'm doing SCIENCE and I'm still alive.\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

`require`, or even better, `require_once` should be used exclusively when you want to include code that is actually *required* by the application, e.g. any libraries you need. `include` and its brother, `include_once` should only be used when the included file is not necessary to the execution of your script, such as when you are loading a sidebar or some tangental content.

The only real **difference** between the two statements is that is the file is not found, `require` with throw a fatal error, and `include` will just throw a warning and go on happily chugging away.

I believe that both `require` and `include` are loaded and parsed in exactly the same manner. If `require` would load a file in a given context, so would `include`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally always use `require_once`, I find in most cases it's what you need (either you get the page once or you halt the script). And `include` throws warnings that you need to hide if you want to "try" including stuff. But that's just bad programming practice, a simple `if (file_exists($file)) require_once $file;` does the trick and totally beats `include`.

So in my opinion, `require` wins by far.

PS: Beaten by a sec !

Comment: How does this answer the question?